# Trouble with Method and Return Value Calculation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I created a method to calculate a simple calculation.

I want the method to return an int and take 2 int parameters.

I created a class called calculation. I imported calculation into the viewController.m and created an action 2 textFields and a text Label. I am using this view for testing the method.
My method return 0 in the calculation. What am I doing wrong? It's so simple but I can't seem to figure out where I'm making my mistake. Here is the code.

Calculation.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Calculation : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) int odometerStart;
@property (nonatomic) int odometerEnd;
@property (nonatomic) int odometerTotal;

- (int)mileageStart:(int)start mileageEnd: (int)end;    

@end
```

Calculation.m

```
#import "Calculation.h"

@implementation Calculation
@synthesize odometerEnd, odometerStart, odometerTotal;      


- (int)mileageStart:(int)start mileageEnd:(int)end
{
    odometerStart = start;
    odometerEnd = end;
    odometerTotal = end - start;        
    return odometerTotal;
} 
@end
```

viewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MileageViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)calculateMileage:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *startLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *endLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *displayLabel;
@end
```

viewController.m

```
#import "MileageViewController.h"
#import "Calculation.h"

@implementation MileageViewController
@synthesize startLabel;
@synthesize endLabel;
@synthesize displayLabel;

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setStartLabel:nil];
    [self setEndLabel:nil];
    [self setDisplayLabel:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (IBAction)calculateMileage:(id)sender {        
    Calculation *mileage = [[Calculation alloc] init];

    int odomStart = [[startLabel text] intValue];
    int odomEnd = [[endLabel text ] intValue];
    [mileage mileageStart:odomStart mileageEnd:odomEnd];
    mileage.odometerTotal = displayLabel.text.intValue;
    NSLog(@"THe total is %d", mileage.odometerTotal);
```

My total keeps equaling 0. The calculation isn't being calculated.

Comment: and what if you try hardcoding values? eg: `[mileage mileageStart:10 mileageEnd:20]`?

Comment: Yes, I tried adding values and I get the value of 0 also.

Comment: although it is not much code, it is hard to read. the indentation and random empty lines sucks.

Comment: You can't post a question without adding the code in the proper format, maybe you should look at it on a computer or turn your phone sideways but your comments aren't needed if it doesn't support the question in any way.

Comment: proper code formatting increases the readability. Better readability helps others to understand your code and identify issues more easily. So my comment supports the question. the `- (IBAction)calculateMileage:(id)sender` has 7 written lines but spans over 18. other method arent any better. if you would limit empty line to a sense-ful minimum, much less scrolling would be needed. stack overflow is a service for professional programmers. If you cant handle criticism you should consider using another site.

Comment: I fixed the formatting. please do it yourself next time.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is backwards. You're trying to set the value of odometerTotal to the value of your label, but you want it the other way around. It should be:

displayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",mileage.odometerTotal];

However, mileage returns an int value, so you don't really need the odometerTotal property in your Calculation class . You could do it like this:

```
displayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[mileage mileageStart:odomStart mileageEnd:odomEnd]];
```

Comment: Thanks, I reversed the label to the left side and now I see in the value of 0 in the label just like I had the value of 0 in the NSLog statement. Why do I get a value of 0? Why doesn't the method perform the calculation?

Comment: @user1295568, I don't know, it worked for me. You should edit your question to show what code you're using now.

Answer (score -2):

I saw the whole program, and the assignment you did seemed wrong,

the bold pointed was as below:

**mileage.odometerTotal = displayLabel.text.intValue;**

you want to use the calculate class to calculate the total value. while the order should be opposite.

How about this:

```
displayLabel.text.iniValue = mileage.odometerTotal;
```

then use the `NSLog` method to print your expected result.

Comment: This is wrong, `NSString` doesn't have a `setIntValue:` method (which this tries to invoke). It doesn't work like this.